# Is it ever possible to call a non-static member method inside of a static member method in C++?

Tags: c++, static-methods

I doubt this is possible, but it's worth asking: I'd like to call a non-static member function from inside of a static one. I'd like to do it for every current instance of the class. Is it possible?

When I try this in a test class I get the following error:

"cannot call member function 'void TestClass::NonStaticMethod()' without an object"

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that? What kind of class is this? Have you considered how much flexibility you lose once you start talking about "keeping track of every instance"? I can virtually guarantee you, based on years of professional experience, that you will come to regret such a decision.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am a new programmer and indeed this probably isn't the best way to do what I want. However, I still want to know if it's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with some trickery. If you want to keep track of *all* instances, you have to register the instances at class construction time. This is tricky to get right, of course, but here's a rough approach:

```
class Foo
{
    static std::unordered_set<Foo*> instances;

    void do_it();  // non-static member function

public:
    Foo()
    {
        instances.insert(this);
        // ...
    }

    // add copy constructor, move constructor, etc.

    ~Foo()
    {
        instances.erase(this);
        // ...
    }

    static void call_all()
    {
        for (Foo * p : instances) { p->do_it(); }
    }
};
```

You'll have to make sure that *all* constructors perform the registration.

Comment: To illustrate a point that's often lost on new programmers, that access is controlled by type, not through the `this` pointer, I suggest making `do_it` private.

Comment: You'd also need to deal with the implicitly generated copy constructor: either delete it or make it register the object. I guess, I would factor the registration logic into a member or a base to minimize the interference from having multiple constructors and to avoid forgetting to deal with it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: You mean the point that access is per class and not per instance? Hm, perhaps... it's a good point.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Yes, as I said, it's tricky. I added a comment calling attention to the copy constructor.

Comment: Is `(Foo * p : instances)` really one of the things added in C++11?

Comment: @Karl: Yes, it's quite convenient, isn't it?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Yes, naturally :-) I felt lazy typing and didn't want to distract from the main point (a sentiment surely shared by the C++11 committee). I trust anyone is able to interpolate the corresponding C++98 code from this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call a non-static member from inside a static member, and the error message even suggests how.

You need to provide the instance to which the non-static member function will be applied:

```
o.member();
```

or

```
p->member();
```

Same goes for access to non-static member variables:

```
o.var++;
p->var++;
```

As far as doing it on every instance of the class, it's up to you to keep a list somehow.

Comment: The OP wants to make the call *for every current instance*, though.

Comment: Except there is no "current instance" when calling a static method.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yeah, I saw that after writing my answer and was in the editing process when you commented.  Why can't people put an accurate title on questions?

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB: I interpret that to mean "every instance whose lifetime has started and not yet ended", i.e. the ones for which calling a member function is not undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't put an accurate title because I ran out of space. However my question was very concise.

Comment: @Anthony: You could have replaced "Is it ever possible" with "How". SO question titles don't usually have to be very emotional.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly call a non-static method, but if you want to do something on every current instance, you can do so by maintaining a static list of instances and iterating over this list. The constructor of your class can add itself to this static list and the destructor can remove itself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can tweak it a little. Basically Store every instance of the class in the constructor. Now I dont remember C++ much, so the following code might not work,. I'm just trying to give you an idea of what would work

```
class someClass{
static someClass instances[50];
static int count=0;

 void dosomething(){

}

void someClass(){
//Constructor
someClass::instances[someClass::count++]=this;//Store the instance
}

static int theBoss(){
 //This is the static method that calls the non static member.
int ctr=0;
while(ctr<count){                        
instances[ctr++].dosomething();Iterate over the instances and call their non static method
}
}
```

Comment: The only literal numbers in C++ should be `0`, `1` and `-1`, but never `50` :-S

Comment: never used C++ since school, and we only learnt the turbo 3.x version. Things have changed since then

Answer (score 0):

The only time you can legitimately call a non-static function is when you have an object to call the function on.  Since you don't have a `this` in a static function, you can't say `instanceMethod();` or even `MyClass::instanceMethod();`; somehow you have to say `obj.instanceMethod();` or `objPtr->instanceMethod();`.

Note, though, this means if you create an object of your class from within your static function (or can retrieve one), you can call pretty much whatever you like on it.  C++ doesn't by default know how many objects you've created of a particular type or where they are, though, so you have to keep track of this yourself.  One way might be to have a static list/array/map/set/whatever of objects that you add to in the constructor and remove from in the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    void foo(){std::cerr << "foo\n";}
    static void bar(A &a){ a.foo(); }
    void bar1(){bar(*this); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a;
    A b;
    A::bar(a);
    A::bar(b);
    //OR
    a.bar1();
    b.bar1();
return 0;
}
```